# My glass becomes opaque on the bottom

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, glass

I made a wine bottle for a client and when it's turning it becomes opaque at the bottom, really strange and I do not understand why. Do you have any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Any chance you have a second (hidden in viewport) mesh that's showing up in the render?

Comment: No unfortunately. I have a plan under which is rough and makes it appear even more

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your material. Please add an image that shows the nodes and the outliner.